# Consolidate document() dependencies into single XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to consolidate external files into a single XSLT 1.0 file as a transformation is going to be performed in memory without access to the original file structure.
I cannot figure out how to merge in the files which are read into variables.

The original variable declaration looks like this. (the parameter pLang is needed in the select statement I have trouble with):

```
<xsl:param name="pLang" select="'no'"/>
<xsl:variable name="moduleDoc" select="document('Headlines.xml')"/>
```

I have filled the moduleDoc variable with the contents of the Headlines file like this:

```
<xsl:param name="pLang" select="'no'"/>
<xsl:variable name="moduleDoc">
<module xmlns:mmx="http://funx" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:fnc="http://funx/fnc" xmlns:att="http://funx/att" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <document-merge>
        <g-funcs>
            <g name="IssueDate">
                <g-lang xml:lang="no">Fakturadato</g-lang>
                <g-lang xml:lang="nn">Fakturadato</g-lang>
                <g-lang xml:lang="en">Issue date</g-lang>
            </g>
            <!--snip -->
        </g-funcs>          
    </document-merge>
</module>
</xsl:variable>
```

The select statement looks like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$moduleDoc/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g[@name='IssueDate']/g-lang[lang($pLang)]"/>
```

This works fine when the moduleDoc variable is referencing the external file, but after the merge I get a Saxon error:

> To use a result tree fragment in a path expression, either use
>   exsl:node-set() or specify version='1.1'

What is the proper way to access these nodes in the variable?

Answer (score 0):

I ffigured out that the solution is to use the node-set extension in such a way:

```
<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($moduleDoc)/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g[@name='IssueDate']/g-lang[lang($pLang)]"/></b>
```

A namespace declaration is also needed:

```
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
```